# .JOIN JQuery Error Message Displayed On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has days of the week buttons on it and then on a button click i pass the selected buttons to a confirmation `modal` and i have all this working fine.  The issue i have is if i then just close my `modal`, populate my fields then  try re-submitting, i keep getting a error

> .join is not a function

**JQuery**

```
var selectedWkDays = [ ];
var selectedMthDays = [ ];
var selectedMths = [ ];

$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    getSelectedWeekdayValues();
    getSelectedDaysOfMonthValues();
    getSelectedMonthValues();
    $("b[name = 'modalDialPlanTelNo']").html($('#dialPlanTelNo').html());

    if (pageState == 'Inactive' && buttonclicked == 'Add') {
        $('#inactiveAddSuccessModal').modal();
        addModifyRuleFieldSelections();

        // Sets focus to 'Add More Rules' button once modal loaded
        $('#inactiveAddSuccessModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#addMoreRulesButton').focus();
        })
    } else if (pageState == 'Active') {
        $('#activeAddSuccessModal').modal();

        if (buttonclicked == 'Add') {
            $("#addedupdatedtext").html('added');
            $('#addedLastSentence').css("display", "block");
            $('#addAnotherRuleButton').css("display", "inline");
        } else {
            $("#addedupdatedtext").html('updated');
            $('#addedLastSentence, #addAnotherRuleButton').css("display", "none");
        }

        addModifyRuleFieldSelections();

        // Sets focus to 'Close' button once modal loaded
        $('#activeAddSuccessModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#modalCloseButton').focus();
        })
    }
});

// Creates an array for the selected weekdays to pass to modal
function getSelectedWeekdayValues(){            
    /* looks for all weekday buttons and check if it was selected */
    $("#selectWeekdaysSection .btn-primary").each(function() {
        selectedWkDays.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* joins the array which is separated by the comma */
    var wkDaysSelected;
    wkDaysSelected = selectedWkDays.join(', ');

    /* checks if there is selected buttons, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(wkDaysSelected.length > 0){
        /* converts the wording if all weekday buttons selected */
        if (wkDaysSelected == "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun") {
            wkDaysSelected = "All days";
        } else if (wkDaysSelected == "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri") {
            wkDaysSelected = "Weekdays only";
        } else if(wkDaysSelected == "Sat, Sun") {
            wkDaysSelected = "Weekends only";
        } else {
            wkDaysSelected = wkDaysSelected;
        }
    } else {
        /* if no days where selected, sets the default to 'All days' */ 
        wkDaysSelected = "All days";
    }

    selectedWkDays = wkDaysSelected;
}

// Ccreates an array for the selected days of the month to pass to modal
function getSelectedDaysOfMonthValues(){            
    /* looks for all days of the month buttons and check if it was selected */
    $("#selectDaysOfMonthsSection .btn-primary").each(function() {
        selectedMthDays.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* joins the array which is separated by the comma */
    var mthDaysSelected;
    mthDaysSelected = selectedMthDays.join(', ') ;

    /* checks if there is selected buttons, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(mthDaysSelected.length > 0){
        /* converts the wording if all days of the month buttons selected */
        if(mthDaysSelected == "01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31") {
            mthDaysSelected = "All days of the month";
        } else {
            mthDaysSelected = mthDaysSelected;
        }
    } else {
        /* if no days where selected, sets the default to 'All days of the month' */ 
        mthDaysSelected = "All days of the month";
    }

    selectedMthDays = mthDaysSelected;
}

// Creates an array for the selected months to pass to modal
function getSelectedMonthValues(){            
    /* looks for all days of the month buttons and check if it was selected */
    $("#selectMonthsSection .btn-primary").each(function() {
        selectedMths.push($(this).val());
    });

    /* joins the array which is separated by the comma */
    var mthsSelected;
    mthsSelected = selectedMths.join(', ') ;

    /* checks if there is selected buttons, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
    if(mthsSelected.length > 0){
        /* converts the wording if all days of the month buttons selected */
        if(mthsSelected == "Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec") {
            mthsSelected = "All months";
        } else {
            mthsSelected = mthsSelected;
        }
    } else {
        /* if no days where selected, sets the default to 'All months' */ 
        mthsSelected = "All months";
    }

    selectedMths = mthsSelected;
}

$('#activeButton, #addAnotherRuleButton, #addMoreRulesButton, #modalCloseButton').click(function () {
    if (this.id != 'activeButton') {
        location.reload();
    }

    $('#activeButton').addClass('btn-primary');
    $('#inactiveButton').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $('#inactiveButton').addClass('btn-default');

    active();
    pageState = 'Active';
});

// Active button function to set HTML attributes
var active = function () {
    $("#activeInactiveHeader").html('Active');
    $("button[name = 'modifyButton'], button[name = 'deleteButton']").css("display", "block");
    $("#orderPositionRow, #callRangeRow").css("display", "block");

    defaults();
}

var defaults = function () {
    $("#todrexitingrules, #ruleBuilder, #initialAddTip, #dateErrorMessage").css("display", "none");
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: exchanging the variable name words to create a different variable is a very bad practice. Call it something different.

Comment: could you post as working fiddle?

Comment: Why are you assigning string to an array ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complet Jarrod answer.

You can return the value instead set the string into the array. And you can declare the array into the function.

```
function getSelectedWeekdayValues(){  
    var selectedWkDays = [ ];
    [...]
    return wkDaysSelected;
}
```

And In your click event you can set a global variable with the returned value

```
var selectedWeekdayValues;
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    selectedWeekdayValues = getSelectedWeekdayValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have "selectedWkDays" set as a global variable that is an array. The first time the "getSelectedWeekdayValues" function runs it resets the selectedWkDays variable at the end of that function (as mentioned in the comments above) to the value for "wkDaysSelected" which is a string value.

When it runs the second time it is trying to "push" and "join" to a string which doesn't have those methods.